# How to deal with sessions in php?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I'm a newbie in sessions but i really need to use them.
In a lot of examples I see the function`session_set_cookie_params()` before `session_start()`. But when I use it this way i doesn't seem to work as it shoud.
When I put `session_set_cookie_params()` after `session_start()` everything seems to work fine, but `session_set_cookie_params()` returns NULL.
Do you know how to make this work?
Here is index.php

```
<?php
session_name('firstsession');
session_set_cookie_params(7200, '/', 'localhost', true, true);
session_start();

require_once('includes/header.php');
require_once('DatabaseConnectivityManager.php');
require_once('AuthenticationAuthority.php');
$dbManager = DatabaseConnectivityManager::getInstance();
$dbManager->initialize('localhost', 3306, 'admin', '123456789');
$connection = $dbManager->getConnection();
$authenticationAuthority = AuthenticationAuthority::getInstance(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['isLogged'] ) && $_SESSION['isLogged'] = true)  {
    echo 'Hello ';
?>
<br><a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br>
<?php
}
else {
    require('includes/loginForm.php');
    if($_POST) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo 'There is an empty field';
        }
        else{   
            if($authenticationAuthority->checkCredentials($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
                echo 'You are now logged in';
                $_SESSION['isLogged']  = true;
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            else {
                echo 'Wrong pass or username';
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your login HTML?

Comment: <form method="POST">
    username<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        pass<input type="password" name="password" /><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Log in"
</form>

Comment: There's no closing /> for the last input.

Comment: Still no change in the behaviour

Comment: When I  try to log in, it put me in the ELSE statement after:  <br><a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. `void session_set_cookie_params()` is not supposed to return anything. That's why you see that `void` in front of the function name in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: Noo, when I try to log in, nothing happens. It's like the is no POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! I had to make the SECURE parameter FALSE while using localhost.

```
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'localhost', true, true);
```